NoSuchFieldError for Jackson map DeserializationConfig$Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE
I have an application that has been in use for 5+ years. I did not write the app, but recently took over maintenance of it. It has an ObjectMapper that is of type org.codehaus.map.ObjectMapper.
The code has the following line:
this.objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)

It is now throwing the following error:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig$Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE

I can comment out the objectMapper.configure and it works, but I would rather understand the issue. Can you explain what this exception means?

Check if the root element of the JSON you try to deserialize matches with the class name or mapped name of your class.

Did you update Jackson version recently. If so what was the earlier version and the current version
